# How can i get service in adapter class?

Tags: android, service

I use audio in my inflate layout which I use in the adapter, I want to include audio manager service in the adapter to be able to control the audio system. I failed to do that.
A red underline contex in this line of code

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) ContextCompat.getSystemService(>>>Context<<<,AppCompatActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View myView = convertView;
        final IrrVerbeClass myData = getItem(position);

        if (myView == null){
            myView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate
                    (R.layout.irregular_verb_card,parent,false);
        }


        TextView tMeaning = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.cMeaning);
        tMeaning.setText(myData.getMeaning());

            mAudioManager = (AudioManager) ContextCompat.getSystemService(Context,AppCompatActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            ImageView tAudioV3 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.xAudioV3);
            tAudioV3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    releaceMediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),myData.getAudio3v());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOncompletion);
                }
            });
        }
        return myView;
```

Comment: the sample code you've posted lacks the required context ...to answer that. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you . the app don't work with the mentioned sentence. Expression expected  is shown when you hover "Context". the hents you get is : create constant field 'context' in IrrVerbAdapter. - create  field 'context' in IrrVerbAdapter. - move assignment to field declaration

Comment: with "context" I did not mean `Context`, but the context if that snippet, which lacks the signature of that class. it does not tell which kind of adapter this is. passing the `Context` into a constructor might be the most easy, generally speaking.

Comment: regardless of my code, i want to manage the audio system within the adapter class or any other means. the recycle list include audio that should be managed. i need the AUDIO_SERVICE from the system service. how can i reach that.

Comment: as state, provide the context ...to that class, whatever that class may be. if you don't provide the class with a context, just alike you don't provide sufficient context to that question, it won't work. putting into the fragment, which may hold whatever AdapterView might be better, because it would be available further upwards in the structure..